# Do all GPIO pins have a internal pull-up/pull-down resistors?

Tags: gpio, java, pi-b+, pi4j

So question is: Does all Raspberrys GPIO have a internal pull-up/pull-down resistor which can be enabled from program, in my case Java language with PiJ4?

I have Raspberry Model B+.

Answer (score 20):

Yes, all of the B+'s GPIO pins have internal pull-up or pull-down resistors that can be controlled from your code.

Pull-up is 50K min – 65K max.
Pull-down is 50K min – 60K max.

More info on the GPIO can be found [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=62191&p=462221) and [here](http://www.raspberry-projects.com/pi/pi-hardware/raspberry-pi-model-b-plus/model-b-plus-io-pins).

Example usage frm the PI4J [documentation](http://pi4j.com/usage.html#Control_Pin_State):

```
// provision gpio pin #02 as an input pin with its internal pull down resistor enabled
// (configure pin edge to both rising and falling to get notified for HIGH and LOW state
// changes)
GpioPinDigitalInput myButton = gpio.provisionDigitalInputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_02,             // PIN NUMBER
                                                             "MyButton",                   // PIN FRIENDLY NAME (optional)
                                                             PinPullResistance.PULL_DOWN); // PIN RESISTANCE (optional)
```

Comment: To round off your answer it might be worth mentioning that pins 3 and 5 have hard-wired 1k8 pull-ups to 3V3.  These pull-ups are needed for the proper operation  of the I2C bus. A consequence is that the internal pull-downs have no effect on these pins (the internal pull-downs are much weaker than the external pull-ups).

Comment: @Ghanima Is this the datasheet for Model B+? https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bcm2835/BCM2835-ARM-Peripherals.pdf

Comment: @redex, this is the datasheet for the Broadcom SOC chip used in the B+, the "reduced" schematics of the full board are [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/schematics/README.md). For the internal workings of the BCM your link is for sure worth a visit (it's quite exhaustive, and well, 200 pages long).